# Assigning random elements to struct fields

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to write a function that have to assign randomly some elements to a structure. Here's what I tried to do:

```
void assignTerrains (Player* g, Terrain* c, int n){
int i, j, nRand, terrains_for_player;

terrains_for_player = NTERRAINS / n; 

for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(j=0; j<terrains_for_players; )
        do {
            nRand = minRand + rand()%(maxRand - minRand + 1);
        } while (c[nRand].boxType != Terrain);

        c[nRand].idProp = i;
        g[i].capital -= c[nRand].cost;
        g[i].numTerrains++;
        j++
    }
}
```

terrains_for_players is the number of terrains that each player will receive. The number of terrains is 40, but only 24 of them are of the type that can be assigned (boxType have to be terrain). For example: 5 players, so it would be 24 / 5, the first four players will have 5 terrains each, and the last will have 4. The terrains have to be equally assigned to every player, and that have to be random. So i generate a random number until the c at nRand index is of type "terrain", then i do the operations i have to do (subtract money from player, and increment their number of terrains owned. Hope someone can help me! Thanks.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @immibis that function is not doing what it's supposed to do. I'm trying to find out wheres the problem, or maybe someone else have better solutions.

Comment: What exactly should it do, and what is it doing that you don't expect?

Comment: @dbush i described up there what it's supposed to do. It have to assign to N players (given by user, from 2 to 8 max) that 24 terrains, equally. I think something is wrong with the 2 for. When I try executing this, the terrain idProp (proprietary ID) is not changing, and have always the same value

Comment: @kHz So if there are 8 players they each should get 3 terrains?

Comment: @Jacobr365 the number of terrains for each player is given by NTERRAINS (it's always 24) / NPLAYERS, so it would be 3 terrains for each player.

Comment: This code does not compile. If Terrain is a type then while (c[nRand].boxType != Terrain is illegal. You can't check of the value of the box type is equal to a type. Also you have a typo where you use "terrains_for_players" instead of "terrains_for_player" (or the opposite). It's difficult to help you with your problem if the code we are looking at is not the code you are having a problem with.

Comment: @Stuart, yeah it was a typo, I had to translate the code because I'm not coding in english, so i translated it so you can understand it. Terrain is an enum, so yes it's a type.

Comment: while (c[nRand].boxType != Terrain is illegal and will not compile so you could not have executed this code.

Comment: @Stuart so, do you have any solution? Another way to generate a random index, and then  check the type?

Comment: Why do you want a different solution? You know what you are trying to do (and it looks like it might work), you have just made a mistake somewhere. I would suggest that you 1. Edit the code you have shown so that it compiles. 2. Execute this code (make sure the code you are showing us is the code you are having a problem with). 3. Give more information about the problem you are having.

Comment: Saying the program is crashing is not enough. How is it crashing? What happens exactly. Does the program crash with a message (if so what is the message), if there is no message, are you sure the program has crashed (how do you know). You might also want to put some printf's in the code so you can see what your code is doing. You could print out the values of i and j inside the loop. You might also want to print something inside the do while loop so you can see if your code gets stuck inside the loop.

Comment: @Stuart the program crash as soon as executed, without any message (___.exe has stopped working). I actually don't know how to solve that while condition. Maybe if I change Terrain to '0' (since it's an enum and terrain=0) it would solve this? And also, that condition was working. I mean, I tried it and it was generating only indexes where the type of the box was ''terrain''.

Comment: Oh, terrain is a value and Terrain is a type, so you made another typo, 
  
while (c[nRand].boxType != Terrain)  should be 
 
while (c[nRand].boxType != terrain)

Comment: When you say "___.exe has stopped working) do you mean that you get this message from Windows.

Comment: @Stuart yes, windows give the message

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code is ugly (sorry to be so direct). Use meaningful variable names and indent it properly.
2. What's causing the issue (I think, you're not saying what you're expecting and what you're actually getting as result) lies here:

   ```
   do {
       nRand = minRand + rand()%(maxRand - minRand + 1);
   } while (c[nRand].boxType != Terrain);
   c[nRand].idProp = i;
   ```

   In that loop, you try to find a random terrain with the correct type, but you forget to check that the terrains you may find could have been used by another player (a previous iteration of the outer loop) before. Changing the condition to something along ...

   ```
   do {
       nRand = minRand + rand()%(maxRand - minRand + 1);
   } while ((c[nRand].boxType != Terrain) && (c[nRand].idProp != NO_PLAYER));
   c[nRand].idProp = i;
   ```

   ... should solve that.
3. A better way IMO would be to first generate a random permutation of the available terrains, and then have each player take a suitable number of these. Like:

   ```
   Terrain * suitableTerrains = getThat24SuitableTerrains();
   permuteRandom(suitableTerrains); // Using random swapping, choosing random indicies, what ever
   size_t nextTerrain = 0;
   for (player = 0; player < countPlayers; ++player) {
     unsigned terrain;
     for (terrain = 0; terrain < terrainsPerPlayer; ++terrain) {
       // assign suitableTerrains[nextTerrain] to the player
       ++nextTerrain;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: 1) You don't have to be sorry, I know it's not good code, but it's because I started programming just few months ago.
2) I already thought about that! I just have modified the do while condition, but that won't solve the problem :( the program is crashing when being executed, and i can't find the problem really..

Comment: How large is that array pointed to by `c` ? And what's `randMax` and `randMin` ? I'd guess at an out of bounds access.

Comment: c is an array of structure and have 40 elements: the structure itself has 8 fields. rMin is 0 and rMax is 39, so the number generated is index of one of the boxes, and then it checks if it's of the desired type (terrain)

Comment: Hm, is the `g` array of the correct size? In what loop in which iteration does it crash?

Comment: g is allocated dinamically.

Comment: Does it have `n` elements?

Comment: yes, it's a structure of 6 fields, and it's allocated dinamically when program starts: something like malloc(n*sizeof(Player))

Comment: Maybe you should show the code that does the allocation.

Comment: `Player * allocPlayers (GameInfo i){
    Player *player = NULL;
    player = malloc(i.nPlayers * sizeof(Player));
    if(player == NULL){
        exit(-1);
    } else
        return player;`

Comment: That looks ok .. without further input (which loop does how many iterations before crashing) it's hard to even guess anything.